# why SQL server donot create index automatically based on stats?

Tags: sql-server

Over time based on stats SQL server can decide important columns that requires Index, so why not create it by it self ? as we programmer often forget to create Index on important colums used in our where clause and suffer performance issues. I mean If CLR garbage collector can do it then why not SQL server ?

Comment: sql servers have more important things to do with with the cpu cycles available than analyze MASSES of query log data.

Comment: be careful what you wish for, or there will be no jobs for skilled humans

Comment: Is that a feature request for the SQL Server team? Whatever it is - it is off-topic

Comment: Automatically determining indexes to add is a lot different from automatically collecting garbage. Also, determining proper indexes requires more information than SQL Server has - for example, which queries *need* to run fast, and which can be slow? How much disk-space can we use on these indexes? How much can we slow down inserts to maintain these indexes?

Comment: At least I hope it's smart enough to not write my disk full of indexes. And that it is smart enough to not create borderline duplicate indexes. And knows when the cost of keeping it up to date is higher than the won cost when reading.

Comment: Yea ur right cpu cycle are important but it will be very helpful feature like right click and click optimize db

Comment: @SalmanAziz seriously, that sounds like a recipe for disaster

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are not free.  There's a cost to maintaining them, both in disk space in performance on DML operations.  They leave it up to the DBA to determine what should and should not impact operations on the database.